# siri replay's like "Sorry, there was a problem with the app"

Tags: ios, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I was just trying to integrating custom siri intent into my app.i have done code for intent handler and i can able to create shortcut but when i run my shortcut. i'm unable to open my app. see this image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2fby.png

Comment: I am also had same issue. Anyone resolved this issue?

Comment: Is the shortcut present under Settings app and is that phrase correctly associated with that shortcut? Its hard to answer this without looking at the code and settings.

Comment: Any solution for this? I am getting the same problem yet my shortcut appears and phrased correctly. And it appears we are following the same Example https://medium.com/@pietropizzi/a-beginners-guide-to-developing-custom-intent-siri-shortcuts-for-ios-12-a3627b7011af

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to make sure that your Intent does not take too much memory (~<20Mb) and respond in reasonable time (<5s)

Answer (score 1):

If you missed handling intent then also you might come across this error. Check file `IntentHandler.swift`

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension, INSendMessageIntentHandling, INSearchForMessagesIntentHandling, INSetMessageAttributeIntentHandling {

        override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {

            return MyIntetHandler() //Here, If you are returning self that means you have not handled it.
        }
......
```

Sample intent handler code, the intent name I have created is `My`, protocol `MyIntentHandling` is autogenerated you just need to confirm it.

```
class MyIntetHandler: NSObject, MyIntentHandling
{
    func handle(intent: MyIntent, completion: @escaping (MyIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        completion(MyIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: nil))
    }
}
```